# Error while executing test via Jenkins

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, webdriver, continuous-integration

I'm having this error while running my test suite from jenkins and when i run in eclipse via Maven it's working fine,
I'm using the same pom.xml for jenkins which is giving this error:

```
Running TestSuite
 INFO [main] (BrowserManager.java:124) - Connecting to http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/ to check lastest chromedriver release
 INFO [main] (BrowserManager.java:112) - Latest driver version: 2.9
 INFO [main] (Downloader.java:56) - Binary driver previously downloaded /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/webdriver/chromedriver/linux64/2.9/chromedriver
 INFO [main] (Downloader.java:60) - Exporting webdriver.chrome.driver as /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/webdriver/chromedriver/linux64/2.9/chromedriver
Tests run: 4, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 3, Time elapsed: 2.904 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
Setup(webautomation.GetApp)  Time elapsed: 2.218 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/ElementNotSelectableException
    at webautomation.GetApp.Setup(GetApp.java:57)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotSelectableException
    at webautomation.GetApp.Setup(GetApp.java:57)


Results :

Failed tests: 
webautomation.GetApp.Setup(webautomation.GetApp)
  Run 1: GetApp.Setup:57 » NoClassDefFound org/openqa/selenium/ElementNotSelectableExce...
  Run 2: PASS


Tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 18.671 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-10-06T17:27:37+05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 26M/200M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Are you using the same version of Maven and Java for both? In Jenkins, is it a Maven job, or a Freestyle job with a Maven build step?

Comment: It's a maven job and i'm using the same version for maven and java

Comment: Try converting the job to a Freestyle job with a Maven build step. In my experience it will either correct the problem or give a better error message so you can determine what's wrong. Stephen Connolly of the Maven team [considers the Jenkins Maven job type evil](http://javaadventure.blogspot.com/2013/11/jenkins-maven-job-type-considered-evil.html).